# how to make UILabel dynamically without overlapping with other UILabel

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I've tried to search online, but haven't found a clear answer for my issue so I've come to ask for your expert advice. I have a view with 2 labels on it. Both label will display different string length from the plist.

When i run the app, the label will overlapped with other label depending on the string length.

Below is the screenshot for my problem

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change your secondLabel origin.

```
CGRect frame = secondLabel.frame;
frame.origin.y= firstLabel.frame.origin.y + firstLabel.frame.size.height;
[secondLabel setFrame:frame];
```

Answer (score 0):

Better option is to use `UITextView` instead of `UILabel` but if you still want to go with lable then
with the use of below code you can find the height of the text and can set your lable's frame according to that height

```
NSString *text = [arr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
CGSize constraint = CGSizeMake(contentWidth - (CELL_CONTENT_MARGIN * 2), 20000.0f);
CGSize size = [text sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:20] constrainedToSize:constraint lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
CGFloat height = MAX(size.height, 44.0f);
```

here contentWidth is the width of your label and CELL_CONTENT_MARGIN = 10;

Answer (score -1):

Ey, you can solve it in many ways.

For example, you can fill your first label with the dessired text and then call to

```
[label1 sizeToFit]
```

With that call, your label now has the proper size, adapted to the lenght of your text. Now you can just place your second label after your first one.

```
label2.frame = CGRectMake (x, label1.frame.size.height + ..., .....)
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score -1):

You need to set the 'Y' of second label. Take the Height of first label text and then set it to the Second Label 'Y'.
Hope it'll help you.

```
CGSize LblSize=[[Label1 text] sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0f] constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(320.0f, 400.0f)];


UILabel *Label2=[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:Label2Rect];

CGRect Label2Rect=[Label2 Frame];
Label2Rect.origin.y=LblSize.height+30.0f; //add some extra spaces, I have added 30.0f here

[Label2 setFrame:Label2Rect];
```